# Ajax async true gets timeout issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, node.js, python-requests

I am using **django, nodejs, ajax request**.

In Django I am using **requests** library for sending the REST request to Node.js

I am getting timeout issues and some times web page got broken when using async true in ajax request.

**I had given simple example as follows**

The concept is I have variable called `arr = ["INDIA", "USA","UK","CANADA"]`

> AJAX  -----Request----->   DJANGO -------Request-------> NODEJS 
>   (Giving each country information)
>
> AJAX  <--------Response-------   DJANGO  <--------Response------- NODEJS

```
$(function() {
    $.each(arr, function( key, value ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/country/",
            data:{country:value},
            dataType : 'html',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 10000000,            
            async: true,
            success:function(data){
              $('.country').empty();
              $('.country').html(data);        
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
              console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus);
            }
        });    
    });
});
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

> INDIA is incredible
>   USA is happy country
>   ERROR: timeout
>   ERROR: timeout

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

> INDIA is incredible
>   USA is happy country
>   UK is cool contry
>   CANANDA is secure country

Comment: `async: true` is the default. no need to specify it.

Comment: I agree with you. what is the problem for getting timeout issue